# Regular expression to split a huge string into multiple sets of key-value pairs

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, split

I've a huge string which contains many sets, each is separated by `,`. Each set has key-value pairs in it, each pair is separated by `&`.

Here is small example,

```
tag=43&id=8787&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis"&quality=medium,type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis"&quality=medium&tag=172&id=8978,tag=41&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis"&id=1738&quality=medium
```

This string has the following sets (3 sets, each separated by `,`):

```
tag=43&id=8787&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis"&quality=medium

type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis"&quality=medium&tag=172&id=8978

tag=41&type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis"&id=1738&quality=medium
```

I want to write a regular expression to split the original strings into sets of key-value pairs. I tried this,

```
sets = huge_string.split(',')
```

But obviously this would not work, as there is a comma inside *one* key-value pair also:

```
type=video/webm;+codecs="vp8.0,+vorbis" # <--- this is causing problem!
```

Here the `,` is causing problem.

How to write regular expression to accomplish this task? I'm using `Python 3.3.1`.

**Now that I don't know how many pairs will be there, and in what order.**

Comment: According to the example you have provide you may split by `,(?=\w)` this will ensure to match any `,` that is followed by `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` since I noticed that the "problem comma" is followed by `+`. Also if you have control over generating this huge string, try to use another delimiter.

Comment: To make it stricter use `,(?=[a-zA-Z])`.

Comment: Where does the big string originally comes from?

Comment: @nhahtdh: It comes from a site, such as this :  http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=q5sOLzEerwA and it gets the video info in simple text, given a video id. I parse this simple text to get the string which I want to split.

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't know how you end up with that string. I have tried doing this before (but on `watch` page, not the `get_video_info` API, which is a cleaner way), and I can get a list of `url=http...` normally.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Could you post an answer *as an alternative way* to achieve what I'm doing? (you now know what I'm trying to do)

Comment: @Nawaz: Actually, I don't know the full picture - since the link you posted doesn't really contain anything similar to the string you have. I can post a solution, but it will be based on the link you posted http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=q5sOLzEerwA

Comment: @nhahtdh: The [link](http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=q5sOLzEerwA) I posted, gets a text from server; this text contains name-values, so the string which I posted is basically a value associated with a name `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map`.

Comment: @Nawaz have you tried my regex ? You seem to completely ignore it, at least give some feedback

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: Yes. I tried that. It works great. Thanks. But since I'm learning python and regex both, I'm exploring other solutions also.

Comment: @Nawaz: Check my edited solution. I honestly don't know how you end up with the string in the question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would parse the [response by Youtube API](http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=q5sOLzEerwA):

```
# content is a str that stores the content of the link
query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(content)

fullurls = query['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0].split(',')
data = [urllib.parse.parse_qs(i) for i in fullurls]
print(data)
```

This will output a list of `dict` that stores all the information of each of the links. Of course, the code above is a demonstration of concept. Assumptions should be cut down and checks should be added in actual code.

The Youtube API returns a response of MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so we need to use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to decode it.

The `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` key contains value which is a **comma-separated list** of **URL encoded strings**, so we need to split it along the commas `,` and decode each of the tokens with `urllib.parse.parse_qs`. There is no worry about the commas in codecs description, since they are already URL encoded, thus will not interfere with the splitting.

Comment: This code doesn't work as it doesn't get me any meaningful data. How could you do `split(',')`? It is the same problem I've, no?

Comment: @Nawaz: It can be split by `,` - I assure you that. The `,` in `vorbis,...` is encoded as `%2C`, so the only `,` are the separators.

Comment: `query['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0].split(',')` gives error saying `KeyError: 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'`. I think it is because `content` is bytes, so `query` contains dictionary of bytes. So I did this : `query[b'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0].split(',')`. Now it is able to find the key (notice the prefix `b`) but now it says, `TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API` possibly because of `split()`.

Comment: When I changed `query['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0].split(',')` to `re.split(b',', query[b'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0])` it works. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: Actually, I wrote: `content is a str that stores the content of the link`. If you download with `urllib.request`, then it is very likely that you get back a `bytes` data type, which you can use `str` constructor to decode to `str` with `ascii` encoding: `str(downloadedcontent, 'ascii')`

Comment: That works great. Thanks. I want to understand the difference between `downloadedContent.decode('utf-8')` and `str(downloadedcontent, 'ascii')`? The first one doesn't work, which is what I was doing before.

Comment: @Nawaz: They shouldn't be that much different http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#str and http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode. As for the codec, ASCII should be fine, but I think UTF-8 should also work, since there should be nothing that can cause trouble.

Comment: Will not `decode('utf8')` also decode the comma which is present in the value associated with `type`?

Comment: @Nawaz: `decode` in Python means you decode the bytes into character with certain encoding. For example 0xE2 0x80 0x87 means character U+2007 in UTF-8 encoding. It has nothing to do with the percentage encoding.

Comment: Alright, it is getting complicated for me to understand. I need to experiment with it, and explore a bit more about this territory of encoding and decoding. Thanks for all your help. :-)